# ADB works in linux terminal but don't works in Android Studio

Tags: linux, android, android-studio, adb

I try run application in Android Emulator inside Android Studio. Emulator works but when I run my apk in emulator I get error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.'
```

I enter `adb devices` in terminal of Android Studio for check adb. I get error

```
List of devices attached
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
error:
```

But this command successfuly works in standart terminal.

I tried enter  `adb kill-server`but it doesn't help.

My OS is Linux Mint 18.1
Android Studio version is 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root, create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` and add a line like this to give permissions to anyone in the plugdev group:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

In this example, the vendor ID is samsung. You need to use the vendor ID for your device, which can be obtained by running `lsusb` and searching for a line like:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 048e:9e18
```

In this example your vendor ID would be 048e, so you would have to replace 0bb4 with 2a47. The correct line would thus read:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a47", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Now assign read permissions on the files, reload udev and reload the adb daemon:

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```